# Which answer should be accepted if the first one (chronologically) takes the most important step, but the second is more complete?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

[Link to my puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119343/find-the-pattern-and-fill-in-the-question-mark).

The answer written by gsomani is in my opinion more important. The puzzle only has a single step pattern to discover, which they found, but fell short at the last step because they weren't aware of Kelvin and Rankine scales.

The answer written by Evergalo piggybacks off the first, but is a complete solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're *allowed* to accept any answer you want. I don't think either of your two options would be bad to accept - it's up to you.

But in general, I personally see acceptance of an answer as officially declaring "this is the complete answer to the puzzle". The accepted answer is given the most prominent spot for anyone who looks at the puzzle in the future, and it may be the only answer they read.

In the case here, where person A posts an answer getting most of the way there, but person B finishes it off, you'll probably want to upvote both answers. But besides that, you have a few options:

1. Accept person B's answer.
2. Accept person A's answer.
3. Give one or both of the answers a bounty.
4. Write your own "canonical" answer, crediting person A and person B for their contributions to the solve.
5. Add a comment on person A's answer encouraging them to add in the new information supplied by person B; when they do, accept it.

Any of these options might be acceptable depending on the situation. In this particular case, since you believe that the first answerer solved the bulk of the puzzle, I'd probably go for option [5]. I also wouldn't be surprised to see option [1] or [2], just accepting either of the two answers without any further action. (I'd be somewhat surprised to see [3] or [4], because the puzzle is so small, but there's nothing wrong with doing those either.)

In the end, it's entirely up to your judgement.

Comment: Is it rude/officious to green check B's answer but request B to credit A's contribution in B's answer? Or should OP keep silence, it's none of OP's business (A can request B on their own if they want to)? - [The case](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/119782/halloween-magic#comment334504_119855)